# I've got different behavior for object assign on localhost vs Server

Tags: javascript, vue.js, axios

Why the Object.assign works fine on Localhost but on server it does not ?

My vue app is hosted on S3 and everything works fine besides the Object.assign.

The remote api is being called properly and the update is ok, but the object is not being assigned and I got an empty error in the catch.
log for console.log(JSON.stringify(e)) is just {}.

```
      axios
        .put(this.url + "/client/" + item.id, {
          name: item.name,
          contactName: item.contactName,
          phoneNumber: item.phoneNumber,
          email: item.email,
        })
        .then((response) => {
          Object.assign(this.client[this.editedIndex], item);
        })
        .catch((e) => {
          console.log(JSON.stringify(e));
          this.dialogError = true;
        });
    },
```

I have tried change the object assign like this Object.assign({}, this.client[this.editedIndex], item);, but I got any unexpected behavior.

Comment: if you see an empty error in your catch log then you can be sure that the Object.assign is. Maybe change console.log(JSON.stringify(e)) to console.error(e); to get the real error message. Maybe the then function raises a javascript error which goes unseen, maybe a network request failed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error you get is most likely caused by an empty value of `this.client[this.editedIndex]`. Take a look on the below example:

```js
(new Promise((resolve) => { resolve(); }))
  .then(() => { 
    console.log('then'); 
    Object.assign(undefined, {a: 1}); 
  })
  .catch((e) => { 
    console.error('error', JSON.stringify(e)) 
  });
```

prints:

```js
then
error {}
```

Replacing `undefined` by `null` gives similar results. Therefore I would assume that there is no value at your `this.client` at `this.editedIndex` key.

In error logging you should avoid using JSON.stringify() with [Error](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Error) instances, as JSON.stringify does not know how to handle it:

```
> JSON.stringify(new Error('message'))
'{}'
```

You are losing all the information - like message, stack etc.

Comment: Yes the problem was it! thanks @Beniamin H and Joshua Angnoe, the this.editedIndex was not the right index, so this.client was undefined. I change the way I was loging the error and got it as you guys told me to do so. Thanks a lot.